# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting ForbiddenAttributesError in Rails 4

Below is my request parameters

```
Request parameters  
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"q+s0otvtcblkkN3r0DoJZ8rZveSDb75uI9I9UDxvWFA=", "product"=>{"name"=>"Product test", "description"=>"asdadasdasdsd", "product_url"=>"", "image_id"=>"", "request_info"=>"0", "email_notification"=>"0", "emails"=>"", "user_id"=>"1", "booth_ids"=>["", "1"]}, "commit"=>"Create Product", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"products"}
```

Below is my strong params

```
def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :product_url, :image_id, :request_info, :email_notification, :emails, :user_id)
    end
```

Is there something that I'm missing here?

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    resourcify

  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  has_and_belongs_to_many :booths

  has_one :uploaded_file, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, :description, presence: true
  validates :user, associated: true, presence: true
end
```

Comment: `booth_ids` are missing.

Comment: @Santosh thanks, I've tried adding it in but it's still not working with same error

Comment: Im having the same problem, i have this: `{:booth_ids => []}` in the `permit` maybe it works for you, not for me tho

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the protected_attributes gem. Do you have that in your Gemfile? If so, remove that from your Gemfile so you could instead use the Strong Parameters way of whitelisting attributes. If you prefer to use protected_attributes, you have to use `attr_accessible :name, :description, etc...` in your Product model. I suggest you use strong parameters though since it is more flexible. You could easily do something like having different whitelisted attributes with strong params.

The ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError only appears when you have the protected_attributes gem in Rails 4 or if you're using Rails 3 and earlier versions. Strong Parameters does not raise that error. Another evidence you'll see why that isn't an error raised by Strong Parameters is that it is namespaced as an ActiveModel error. Strong Parameters is part of the ActionController module and not ActiveModel.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm not using protected_attributes gem. I'm using Rails 4. I just updated my question to include the Model. Could this be the problem?